# How can I combine rows in a CSV?

Tags: excel, perl, shell, csv

I have a CSV file with three comma-delimited fields that looks like this:

```
THIS_IS_A_RECORD,email1domain.com;,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
ANOTHER_RECORD,email1domain.com;,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
,,email@domain.com;
```

I would like to merge the rows so my output looks like this:

```
THIS_IS_A_FIELD,email1domain.com;,email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;
ANOTHER_FIELD,email1domain.com;,email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;
```

The third field from the `,,email@domain.com;` rows should be appended to the end of the last complete record. My goal is to import the output into a MySQL database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about putting all your data in one row, but you certainly don't need to do that to import it into MySQL. MySQL can import CSV files directly using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) (or the command line utility [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html)). You can specify the delimiter, line ending character, whether fields are quoted, etc.

Comment: *"My goal is to have it all in one row..."*  But you show two rows for your desired output.  Do you want it *"all in one row"* as you've stated or in two rows as you've shown?

Comment: You do realize that if that is really a CSV, `,,email@domain.com;` is not a continuation of the previous line, but rather a separate record with the first two fields being empty, right?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - that is the issue. Each email is a seperate record. I uploaded a screenshot. screenshot http://rleon.net/mystuff/my_stuff/excel_1.png

Comment: @Kenosis is correct. the emails under are a seperate record that should be in the same record.

Comment: If that's the case, you probably want to strip off the extra commas, so your final output should look more like: `field1,field2,email1;email2;email3 ...` instead of `field1,field2,email1;,,email2;,,email3 ...`

Comment: Maybe I made this confusing by naming this field1 and field2. It would be more accurate to say RECORD_1 , RECORD_2. If you look at my screenshot FIELD_1 has one manager email and a number of members. FEILD2 is a seperate record with one manager email and a number of members. So if I can get it like this. `FIELD1,email1domain.com;,email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;` `FIELD2,email1domain.com;,email@domain.com;email@domain.com;email@domain.com;`

Comment: Or in excel join the list of members to one row. I can do this by hand but these is hunderds of records that I have to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Given your dataset, the following will do what you want:

```
perl -pe 'chomp; print "\n" if /^[^,]/ && $. > 1; s/,//g if /^,/' inFile > outFile
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although this solution matches the desired output given in the question, it leaves a bunch of extra commas in the last "field", which would complicate the OP's stated goal of importing the records into MySQL. If you look at the OP's latest comment on the question, the extra commas are removed.

Comment: @Kenosis that was very helpful. I can remoove the double comma using notpad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '
    length($1) {if (line) print line; line=""} 
    {line = line $0}
    END {if (line) print line}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like this solution. It assumes nothing about which columns (after the first) contain email addresses.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
my @labels;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my ($label, @emails) = split /,/;
  @emails = grep $_, @emails;
  push @labels, $label if $label;
  push @{ $data{ $labels[-1] } }, @emails if @labels;
}

print join(',', $_, @{ $data{$_} }), "\n" for @labels;
```

**output**

```
THIS_IS_A_RECORD,email1domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;
ANOTHER_RECORD,email1domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;,email@domain.com;
```

Comment: The OP wants to remove commas from the lines which begin with a comma.